# react redux router in not defined in action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

My react redux work flow like:

My `action.js`

```
export function loginSuccess(response){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      console.log(getState())
      dispatch({ response, type: LOGIN })
      console.log(getState())
      router.transitionTo("/profile")
  };
}
```

I have `routes.js`

```
const routes =  (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Login} />
        <Route name="profile" path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Route>
  </Router>
)

export default routes
```

and my `root.js`

```
class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store } = this.props
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <ReduxRouter />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default Root
```

When doing this it gives me error `router` is not defined ?

What's wrong in here? Why am I getting this error? I have provided `this.props` in my `Provider`.

Anyone plz guide me through this... Banging my head on this.

Comment: I have passed it as `this.props`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an object called `router` in your `loginSuccess` function which unless it's a global variable will throw a TypeError.

You need to pass it to your `loginSuccess` function in order for it to work.

```
function loginSuccess(response, router) {
    router.transitionTo('/');
}
```

Comment: how can I get `router` in my calling method ? I am firing this action from another action that is called from DOM .. there i did `const {router} = getState().router` and I did like `dispatch(loginSuccess(response, router)`.. Is this a way to do it ?

Comment: Yes. That's the way :)

Comment: I did so and it says transitionTo is not defined.. or transitionTo is not a function

Comment: I did like `getState().router.transitionTo("/profile")`